# Rescomm API based call towards webRTC client issue

Tags: api, webrtc, sip, mobicents, restcomm

I would like to perform a call using API towards webRTC based client.

The scenario is:

1. Login as alice to olympus client (I also tried with different one with the same results).
2. Trigger the simple sip call to alice client ( curl -X POST http://$USR:$PASS@$IP:8080/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/$SID/Calls.json -d "From=System" -d "To=client:alice" -d "Url=http://$IP:8080/restcomm-rvd/services/apps/dial/controller?dial_to=6671" - dial aplication is a simple one, which makes SIP dial to the number given as dial_to parameter).
3. On client's side nothing happens. I can see in the restcomm logs, that call is in trying state, and after a whie it gets timeout.

The exactly same scenario works well, when the call is towards standard sip client. Rescomm and browser, that runs olympus is in the same IP network (no NATin, fws etc).

Could someone help me with this issue ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment RestComm does not support outbound calls to WebRTC clients.

The problem is that when you register a client, RestComm has no reliable way of knowing if said client is WebRTC or not. When you do the outbound call, the SDP offer generated by the media server will use the RTP/AVP profile whereas WebRTC requires RTP/SAVP.

This is a known issue and as far as I see it there are two possible ways of solving it: the first is through SDP renegotiation and the second is for the offer to contain the two media sessions (two m= line for RTP/AVP and RTP/SAVP) and let the client choose one.

You can find the official Mobicents MS issue [here](https://github.com/Mobicents/mediaserver/issues/29).

Are you interested in contributing for this issue by any chance?

Regards